# Official policy on copying content

Tags: discussion, legal, dmca-notice

What's the official stance on copying content?

I'm not after the community stance on the matter. I've read through the following

https://stackexchange.com/legal

and found the disclaimer (emphasis mine),

> 5. Warranty disclaimer
>
> Stack Exchange has no special relationship with or fiduciary duty to
> Subscriber. Subscriber acknowledges that Stack Exchange has no control
> over, and no duty to take any action regarding: which users gains
> access to the Network; which Content Subscriber accesses via the
> Network; what effects the Content may have on Subscriber; how
> Subscriber may interpret or use the Content; or what actions
> Subscriber may take as a result of having been exposed to the Content.
> Much of the Content of the Network is provided by and is the
> responsibility of the user or subscriber who posted the Content. Stack
> Exchange does not monitor the Content of the Network and takes no
> responsibility for such Content. Subscriber releases Stack Exchange
> from all liability for Subscriber having acquired or not acquired
> Content through the Network. The Network may contain, or direct
> Subscriber to sites containing, information that some people may find
> offensive or inappropriate. Stack Exchange makes no representations
> concerning any content contained in or accessed through the Network,
> and **Stack Exchange will not be responsible or liable for the accuracy,
> copyright compliance, legality or decency of material contained in or
> accessed through the Network**.

So it would appear that Stack Exchange waives any legal responsibility. But, what's the official stance on copying content from third parties? I see no official guidance on the matter anywhere.

The thing that worries me is that a lot of the community encourages copying content and then linking to it. What's the **official** stance on this? Is this encouraged or discouraged? I'm seeing whole documents of other peoples' and other companies content copied into Stack Exchange sites, because the community doesn't like links because *"links break"*.

Comment: `The thing that worries me is that a lot of the community encourages copying content and then linking to it` - A lot of people copy content, but I've never seen people encouraging others to copy content. Rather, I've only seen the opposite.

Comment: You may have gotten that mixed up, people don't encourage copying content, but they encourage linking to it IF copying.

Comment: [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 6):

> But, what's the official stance on copying content from third parties. I see no official guidance on the matter anywhere?

See Chapter 15 in the [Terms of Use](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Victims of copyright violations on Stack Overflow can file a [DMCA takedown](http://www.dmca.com/FAQ/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown).

The [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) regulates how copyright violations in user contributions on web sites under American jurisdiction are dealt with. It keeps the site owners free from liability for the violation, as long as they react correctly to any takedown notices that occur.

Comment: That's what Stack Exchange will do if someone complains. I'm asking about policy on copying content from other peoples websites before they complain.

Comment: @Harry what other policy could/should they state other than "don't break the law"? Some (most) content on the web is protected and copying it onto Stack Overflow is illegal (unless it's fair use). That's where the takedown comes in. Other content is licensed under a more liberal license, allowing sharing with attribution, or a link, or when republished under a similar license. Some content is in the public domain. Copying these kinds of on Stack Overflow, when done right, can be legal, but I don't see how SO could create an official policy on this that would cover all possible scenarios.

Comment: Regardless of legality, the rules on the "how to reference" page linked above always apply. You definitely don't want to just copy third-party resources wholesale, you want to write an answer on your own and support it with select quotes from the resource. There also is a community policy on [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071)