# A welcoming way to winnow out the "dumb" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, low-quality-posts

Dumb questions. We have all seen them. Like the one I just saw that with this Java code sample,

```
while (!name.equals("out")) {
    System.out.println(name);
    break;
}
```

that asked why it was not "looping". (Answer: the `break` statement!)

OK. That's a dumb question ... but we don't want to dump on the person who asked it, because that's unfriendly. (He or she is a beginner at Java and at Stack Overflow.) And the question does warrant a light-weight answer. (It did satisfy the basic requirement of intelligibility, and there is a limit on the amount of meaningful research that a beginner programmer can do.)

But, we don't really want questions like that in the long term. They help nobody but the OP. Once someone has answered, they are (frankly) a waste of time to even read. Not to mention a bit depressing.

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. We used to have a closure reason which was basically that the question was only of relevance to the OP. That was removed. How about we bring it back?
2. Variation on 1: there is a closure reason, "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." How about tweaking that to include "beginners mistakes" ... appropriately worded?
3. Variation on 1: a closure reason for "beginners mistakes" ... appropriately worded.
4. How about, a new class of closure reasons that can only be used for questions that have an answer (or an answer with a non-negative score)? These would result in different messaging to the user that doesn't suggest they have done anything wrong or that they should edit their question to improve it.

   In a sense, this is how dupe closure is handled.

Discuss :-)

Comment: I think we forget the most important part: the number of users that will jump on those *dumb* questions to answer them to get *easy* reputation. Even worst, they will also upvote them to attract more attention so they also get more upvotes. How can we also avoid this?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong (IMO) in people getting reputation from answering dumb questions.

Comment: *we don't really want Questions like that in the long term.* Spitballing... I agree that we don't want these questions long term, maybe instead of closure, these can be a direct deletion type reason? A banner could be put up on the question for the question asker to see that says "Question Archived" with a little blurb about how such questions are not useful to other users, and the post is archived to maintain the high quality question and answers visible, then the question gets deleted when the banner is put on. Similar to closure, but without the bad connotation, and it gets it off the site.

Comment: @DavyM I like how you're thinking. I think we need something outside the box.

Comment: The [new-nav] project failure was very, very painful.  That SO management did not insist on an instant v2 version was criminal.  But hard to guess what they were thinking, there might be more to it.  All you can do now is wait for an hour.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Dunno about you but I happily downvote the answers to the really dumb questions...

Comment: @StephenC of course there is nothing *wrong* answering those questions but such thing will increase the number of dump questions and encourage them and it will make the cleaning job more difficult. Even if at the end the question will get closed, we will still get more and more because the logic is "I don't mind if my question will get closed if at the end I have the answer". So we should somehow educate users to better consider closing than answering, especially high reputation users (Yes I see a lot of High rep answering dump questions ...)

Comment: @NickA downvoting isn't enough, I try my best until it get deleted ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alas, I do not have the rep to del-vote

Comment: While I feel a lot of sympathy for your concern, I'm afraid that adding more/better  closure reasons won't have any effect. As indicated by @TemaniAfif, the vast majority of people sees a "dumb" question as an "easy" question. **Voting to close is the last thing people do.** Sometimes I doubt whether they even know they can. That's my greatest concern: seeing questions that clearly should be closed immediately taking too much time for five users to realize it. *If* we want to discourage "dumb" questions we need users that deal with them, using the tools that are available already.

Comment: Who decides a question is dumb?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Comment: @DavyM Nice try but doesn't discourage more of that ilk from being posted in the future because it does not punish the person who posted it. You're going to end up with two "streams" of questions - good ones, and crap ones that people keep posting to "get their help" regardless of the inevitable archival. Then you have two sites. Who's going to moderate the latter? It might sound harsh to "punish" people who post rubbish but at the end of the day incentives matter otherwise what is the point. Being nice to everybody at all costs _does not work_ and I can't stress this enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Even as (relatively speaking) a complete newbie in the different aspects of programming, social interaction and this site, I must disagree with you here: "Being nice to everybody at all costs" is literally the *only* goal that *really matters* in the end.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit I'm generally with you on that point. Yet from how I see it, we already have two classes of users, those who post well prepared questions, and those who expect Stack Overflow to solve their problems and code for them like it's a help desk. Currently we don't have a good way to get rid of the second style of questions when they are clear, specific, but just lazily not researched or otherwise dumb, and they just get downvoted. I might flesh this out into an answer for more feedback, but I'm thinking "How can we get these questions off the site?" and this came to mind.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yikes. So the author's theses are that Stack Overflow is "toxic and hostile" towards beginners, that the site's curators can be safely ignored because they're "neckbeard"s who live in "their mom’s basement", but also that if you're a beginner you should toughen up and "don’t let that shit get to you" and it's your own fault anyway because your questions are "terrible", and also April Wensel in particular is too hypersensitive for it to ever be possible to avoid offending her? The total lack of charity towards *anyone* being written about makes it kind of distasteful, to me.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374701/what-to-do-when-the-question-is-so-trivial-rtfm-that-it-doesnt-even-have-a-prop

Comment: @MarkAmery oh yeh, there's a lot of vitriol. It's still interesting. It goes "There’s nothing worse than a question like this:" and then gives some really good suggestions about how to ask.

Comment: Do you mean that SO is not a place for people with problems of programming logic? Is there anywhere in SO with a list of "askable" questions permitted?

Comment: @PSyLoCKe The problem isn't it being about programming logic. Stack Overflow is meant to be a library of questions and answers with long term value -- things to discover, share, and refer to. The fundamental problem with the example question is that it has very little long-term value.

Comment: This YouTube video (["The Hard Parts of Open Source" by Evan Czaplicki](https://youtu.be/o_4EX4dPppA)) made me think of SO's problems. I believe mid-to-late in the video, Evan discusses the same issue that SO is having with regards to different expectations in questions. From memory, he discusses an idea for a system to guide users to ask the best questions in the right category (the example in the OP here might be *learn*)

Comment: There's a difference between *dumb* and *beginner* - as shown in Yvette's answer. IMHO, There's nothing wrong with answering *beginner* question, though most of the time they can be easily closed as dupes. Many old questions, some of them with high scores for both question and answer(s), are beginner questions.

Comment: How about this, higher rep users can only see questions with a certain number of upvotes and views 4 or 5 votes and a 100 views maybe and bounty questions are visible to everyone regardless.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Only stupid people. Does that help? OK, that was wrong, but I couldnt resist. So, seriously: nothing we say, or not say here, or do, or not do, or "suggest" will have any meaningful effect. "Quality matters" only matters to a very specific subset of this community. And from what you could read here over the past months, the people running the show and paying the servers, aren't exactly in the midst of that subset. New users matter, question count matters, growth matters ... quality ... not so much.

Comment: @DavyM I certainly approve of attempting to find a better solution!

Comment: @PembaTamang This wouldn't help much: the questions would still exist and be visible to most visitors; they would only be [taken out of sight of some of the users better equipped to deal with them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252810/2751851) (including by, when appropriate, actually writing answers  -- vote and view counts are not an infallible indicator of quality).

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2017/05/16/dont-be-a-code-tyrant-be-a-mentor/

Comment: I like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/1426539) proposal by Shog. Rapid deletion can be kinder than closure, since users spend less time exposed to down-votes, hence can be harder to get q-banned.

Comment: @duplode "blind leading the blind"....haha. Still I would say that the idea is not to go black and white and just find a sweet spot to segregate users. We will end up seeing questions near our level of expertise on both ends. Help the new and learn from the old right?

Comment: Let's create https://beginnersToProgramming.stackexchange.com and migrate all those questions there.

Comment: The qualification is subjective, what you think is dumb is not what I think is dumb. So who gets to decide? This simply trades one problem for another, which in my opinion is worse. Live with the problem, it's the lesser of the evils.

Comment: To add a data point to the discussion: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53594667/1630171) is one of the most recent questions in the `powershell` tag. Instead of being closed right away as too broad (or at least a duplicate of an existing question) it has attracted 3 answers so far.

Comment: imho, any question that can be answered by a simple link to an api page for the related language/library/framework is low hanging fruit for "dumb question".  Though it's not so much dumb, and perhaps lazy?  (shrug)

Comment: I only started posting here recently, but I've been consuming this site for *years* it is the *best* site. So - although this is certainly a relevant topic - is there really something broke that needs to be fixed? (Maybe - it's a question not a snark :)

Comment: A question that helps "nobody but the OP" is not necessarily a bad question.

Comment: If we're not going to keep 'dumb' questions, then we should have separate site for those. Then sit back and watch that site's traffic soon dwarf the main site's visits and usage.

Comment: @Christine It might not be a bad question in some general sense, but it is not a good fit for this specific site, as questions here are meant to be useful to others who find it and read it.

Comment: @StephenC maybe people "that get rep by answering dumb questions" usually fall in the class of repwhores: `The "repwhores" who answer everything they can (or can't).` Source: [Help vampires and repwhores should get married](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077). Or, *maybe* they just want to help . . .

Comment: @ouflak It'll be full of newbies and others that don't know what they're doing.  Sure, there'll be a lot of traffic.  There won't be much help, however.  Experts are what drive SO; take those away, and you're left with the very thing SO was created to replace: forums.

Comment: I've recently started picking up LUA in recent months because: Kids kind of interested in the scripting Roblox, new job that actually uses it in anger, programming golf challenges. I don't know how many times I've visited the 'dumb' LUA for-loop question. I've got over 20 years professional experience, not to mention all of the programming I've played around with since I was 13 (bumps it up to well over 30 years). If those kinds of questions aren't here, they will eventually be somewhere else. I don't think the owners of StackExchange are interested in all of that traffic going somewhere else.

Comment: duplode, are you saying we should only have questions that are of interest to a ton of people?

Comment: @Christine "A ton" is too strong a demand (for one, we do have plenty of niche tags and topics here); otherwise, yes, that's the spirit. If a question is formulated in a way that is so closely tied to the asker's circumstances that it becomes difficult for other people to find it, notice its relevance to their own circumstances, and get something useful out of it, it is not a good fit here.

Comment: Related discussion: [*“You're Unclear on What You're Asking”*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291866/2751851)

Answer (score 72):

## Mark basic questions as duplicates

The `break` example has many potential duplicates:

1. [What does break statement do in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334917/what-does-break-statement-do-in-java)
2. [Difference between break and continue statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462373/difference-between-break-and-continue-statement)
3. [Breaking out of a for loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275195/breaking-out-of-a-for-loop-in-java)

These took around 30 seconds to find. If the original poster read and understood all these Q&A, their question would be answered. If not, *they should specify precisely what they don't understand*. I often leave a comment as such:

> Read the marked duplicates. If the use of `break` is still unclear, [edit your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/377349/edit) to specify exactly what is unclear.

For [@YvetteColomb's example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377351/9209546) regarding parameters, you have (among others):

1. [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)
2. ["Parameter" vs "Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument)

There are benefits to this approach:

1. The duplicates have a wealth of information / detail which is likely *not* going to materialise on the basic question asked today. It's also "vetted" via SO's voting mechanism.
2. You are encouraging the poster to learn and come back to edit their question appropriately if their problem is not solved.
3. Especially if you're a gold-badge holder in the relevant tag, you prevent others from wasting their time on a basic question.

In my view, you are serving all 3 main groups alike: the questioner, users reaching the Q&A via Google, and answerers looking for good questions.

Comment: One clear drawback of this approach: the question won't be auto-deleted if it's marked as duplicate. It will continue be on the internet to pollute SO search results. I'd rather close it for other reason and delete it eventually.

Comment: @liliscent, Can voting not take care of this? Does this still stand.. [I can confirm that duplicate questions without answers that are downvoted DO get deleted after 30 days.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210263/383944)

Comment: Interesting. I'm not aware of that. Then this approach is good. +1

Comment: @liliscent and jpp: It is worth noting that the Roomba deletes dupes as `RemoveDeadQuestions` and `RemoveAbandonedQuestions`, but not as `RemoveAbandonedClosed` (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/242059) for an exposition of the criteria). Dupes can be automatically deleted, but it is harder for that to happen than with other close reasons. Two examples, arbitrarily taken from things I cast close votes on: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52109535) was not automatically deleted, while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003568) was caught by the Roomba.

Comment: Do these example duplicates appear in the list of possibly-asked-before if you try to ask that question? If not, fixing that should have TOP priority. If they do *but* the question must still be closed manually as a duplicate of one of them, punish the questioner for not reading that list and thus wasting answerers' time. (Not physically; a pop-up reminder "your previous question(s) already had answers so please check before asking" ought to be enough.)

Comment: @duplode, Isn't the reason [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52109535) wasn't deleted because it didn't have a score `-1` or less. In which case, possibly that's a reasonable result? In other words, users should have been more trigger-happy with the downvote and/or the question should have been closed as a duplicate sooner (which often encourages downvoters).

Comment: @jpp It is reasonable indeed; I just mentioned it because it is worth it to be aware of the difference. (I remember I used to find the Roomba rules extremely confusing before I found the Meta.SE post I have linked to here.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Nice idea, but unfortunately, the "possibly similar or related" search is apparently hostage to the same unsophisticated search engine as the rest of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I disagree, because we shouldn't need to write duplicates for every utterly fundamental thing in a programming language. "How do I write hello world?", "What does the if statement do?" etc. The answer to their question is to read the first chapters in a beginner-level programming book. SO is not some interactive beginner tutorial that should be used in place of traditional studies. By marking such basic questions as duplicate, we signal that asking such poorly-researched questions are fine. While the question is _not_ fine and should be deleted.

Comment: @Lundin, Fair point. I'm not pretending there are no downsides. But after a while on SO, you learn that *nobody can make* beginners read books, and *nobody can stop* them from asking basic questions. Moreover, the powers that be [don't care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348) about improving the community's ability to moderate. 1 vote-to-close (by a gold badge holder) can save *hours* of wasted man-hours. With no structural changes in sight, dupehammer reduces friction *and* saves time.

Comment: Duphammer works for short questions, but not for a chunk of code with multiple separate errors.  I sometimes go for "too broad" in cases where the only really sufficient answer would be a large tutorial custom written for that user to correct all of their misunderstandings / lack of basic knowledge about programming in general.

Comment: @PeterCordes, The problem is *where do you draw the line*? Often the OP *doesn't know* they have 2 errors in their code. They are focusing perhaps on the obvious one. The *real* problem, alas, is they don't have sufficient debugging skills. So while "Too broad" is *technically correct* it often causes friction as OP isn't going to learn how to debug overnight. BUT if you notice a couple of errors and mark some duplicate targets, they have a chance and *might* (if they care) learn how to spot the errors.

Comment: @jpp: yes exactly.  I usually already do exactly what you said, and find one or 2 duplicates that cover the first couple errors I notice.  Too broad I mostly only use on conceptual questions, not questions that are clearly only debugging question.  My previous comment wasn't very accurate.  Unfortunately in the `[assembly]` tag, we get so many questions chock full of multiple errors, like simple loop-logic debugging errors *plus* basic conceptual errors (understanding the difference between an integer and an ASCII decimal string representation of a number is one of the most common.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sometimes you're able to write *excellent* answer to low quality question, it's very rare indeed. Perhaps the tag matters, you're so knowledgable in `x86` which is useful and interesting to many C++ programmers. In C++ tag, however, I believe 70% of the questions should be deleted *immediately* after posting, good-answer-to-bad-question phenomena isn't possible. Actually I vote to close many of them as "asking-us-to-recommand-tutorial". Not particularly accurate, but it's the closest reason I could give.

Answer (score 62):

Throwing in some more ideas for discussion and what I believe is a root cause.

#### Change perspective towards dumb questions

Changing the attitude here is key.

Replacing "dumb" with "beginner".

For instance, one of my earliest questions:

[image]

I did not know what a parameter was.

And then proceeded to edit the question in an attempt to improve it, to a point that was equally fundamental/dumb/beginner and unrecognisable from the first edition.

[image]

I clearly had no concept of program flow.

Now I *know* my intentions were to write a good question. I had no clue how to go about that and didn't know enough about programming to know how to ask a decent question. That is why I am patient with many newcomers. It's not easy learning programming.

#### Site scope - Do beginners belong on Stack Overflow

The real issue for Stack Overflow is not filtering dumb/beginner/fundamental questions. It's really drawing a clear line. Should we accept beginner questions? There's real confusion over this. (at least for me)

> [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
>   Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

"professional and enthusiast programmers", not beginners.

Again people learning programming often don't know how to ask a question due to lack of domain knowledge and are usually the worst at searching for duplicates, because of this.

In the past I've advocated for a beginner sister site. It would solve some issues (create others - it could possibly end up a total cesspool).

The other thing is, I believe we need is some place we can send absolute beginners that's may even be affiliated with our site. Without offending people. There's plenty of places to get tutorials, yet these types of comments tend to be flagged.

Comment: I might be navel-gazing here, but I wonder if we need a new concept to point out which "fundamental" questions we don't want. To me, the feeling is "I know it when I see it", but I lack the vocabulary to put my finger on the difference. Can we identify something that your example and the `break` example in the question have in common that sets it apart from basic questions that clearly belong here?

Comment: @duplode I think you raise a very good point. The fact we are finding it difficult to articulate is part of the problem. It would be good if we could develop some clear parameters for us to follow and be able to cite when dealing with these types of questions. This is where the "lack of minimal understanding" close reason was really helpful.

Comment: Yup, it sounds rather like "minimal understanding", but sharper and narrower somehow. Apparently,  ["unclear" is supposed to cover most cases "minimal understanding" was meant for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252585), but "unclear" isn't a good fit here -- such a question may well be perfectly clear to visitors; if anything, it is more likely to be unclear to the asker themselves.

Comment: @duplode yes indeed. Perhaps it should include that. Unclear to the OP. Not sure how to word it

Comment: The question is dumb, the person asking it might be a beginner.  I've seen some pretty dumb questions asked by people that are not beginners.  That's what happens when you can't scare anybody to take the time to think for a while before asking for help.

Comment: @HansPassant what's "dumb" about it?

Comment: @YvetteColomb To be honest, question like this one is *really* dumb. We don't say it out only for politeness. It's not a beginner question. I would call someone who just finished their first year Java course a Java beginner, but such a beginner might be an expert for this question's asker, who doesn't know what `break` is. Beginner `!=` Absolute clueless

Comment: **Do beginners belong on Stack Overflow?** I wholeheartedly say YES to that. In the end, also beginners should find their answers through Google => StackOverflow. The discussion now focuses on "dumb" vs. "beginner". I think a more appropriate term is **"lazy questions"**. Lazy questions can be asked by any user, beginner or advanced, and that's the type of questions we should filter early, if possible. Your own example shows that at least you were not a lazy questioner. Clumsy, maybe (as we all started). But I think we should be very forgiving toward clumsiness.

Comment: @liliscent *this one is really dumb* But who will judge their own question as "dumb" when posting it? Trolls aside, I think most users won't deliberately ask dumb questions. They may see it was rather stupid *afterwards*, but that's something else. I think we can't blame people for not seeing the obvious error.

Comment: @GertArnold yes it's good when people demonstrate a willingness to help themselves

Comment: @GertArnold Sure we can't blame people for being an absolute beginner, but we *do* blame them for coming to a wrong site for personal tutorial help. There are so many forums on the internet that are dedicated for beginners to learn the very basics, why do they come to a site that is *not* for that purpose? Imagine someday when you search for some problem, many SO links are polluted by these dumb questions, will you still use this site?

Comment: @duplode: I wholeheartedly agree and identify with "I know it when I see it".

Comment: About **"a beginner sister site"** - I've been wondering for some time now if this could be a solution - we could sift through the questions there and select the good ones for "copying" them to Stack Overflow. We also could close questions here with the reason that they should be migrated to the "help desk format"

Comment: @0X0nosugar that sounds like a really good idea.

Comment: The more you learn the dumber you get. A beginner might know 1000 times more than another beginner and think he does not qualify as a beginner, yet the expert will always classify him as a beginner. While I do understand what you are suggesting, even experts sometimes make beginner mistakes, and although they usually have a network of colleagues to interact/rubber duck with,  these beginners do not and will look to SO for answers. I do not think we should  ban beginners to a sister site, i'd say make the experts move to the sister site and leave SO open for ALL. ...

Comment: .. I do understand that this is frustrating, but isn't this what we have moderators for ? Isn't this what we are all here for, to help fellow programmers out ?

Comment: -1 just because beginners **do** belong on StackOverflow.  Arguing that beginners don't belong here would require defining which questions were "beginner enough."  Like @Mukke said, even the most expert programmers occasionally make beginner mistakes.  In addition, I'd lean against just assuming that everyone has taken a beginner programming class.  I know I taught myself C# before I had taken any programming classes.  I also regularly teach myself new programming languages as I grow.  I think jpp has a good solution in just marking duplicate easy questions as duplicates.

Comment: Maybe I got the policy wrong, but I thought we always judge the *question*, not its author. A beginner can ask a good question, I’ve seen that before, and an experienced developer may ask a dump question, I’ve also seen that before. And normally, bad questions are treated the same, regardless of the author.

Comment: It is undeniable that over years, the site has gone from a site mainly for professionals to a site mainly for beginners. It was never meant to be that - SO is not a replacement for traditional studies. Most beginners have the problem that they ask on SO way too early. If someone can't even be bothered to read chapter 1 in a beginner-level programming book, then their problem isn't even related to programming. How did people learn things before the internet? Read a book. Take classes. Ask your teacher. RTFM. If SO seeks to replace that, then SO is harmful for beginners.

Comment: As for the beginner sister-site, it will never work, they would come to SO no matter. What would probably work is to let SO be the beginner-site and then create a sister-site for advanced topics. Where beginner questions and homework are explicitly banned. I'm surprised this has not happened many years ago. SO seems to sit and passively wait for someone else to come and take their veteran users away.

Comment: How about this, higher rep users can only see questions with a certain number of upvotes and views 4 or 5 votes and a 100 views maybe and bounty questions are visible to everyone regardless.

Comment: @Lundin I think times change, I agree with most of what you said, but do keep in mind not every wonna-be (and not in a bad way) programmer has the means to buy a book or get into a course. Using a search index to learn about a topic in a language often ends up on SO, so people result in asking questions if they can't find it on SO, once they had their answer they will not bother to look again and just keep on asking on SO. And that's the culture I think is being addressed in this question. But I do not think we should shout RTFM off the rooftops and hope it will change that culture.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Wasn't that idea up for discussion here already multiple times?

Comment: @DarkMukke If they can afford a PC and internet connection, but not afford books or studies, then maybe they should get their priorities straight... Also, it is not some human right to become a programmer...

Comment: I think some of the objections here, like @GertArnold's, miss a valid and important point. Yes, beginner-level questions are not inherently unwelcome here, and can be very valuable. But I think what Yvette is saying - and I think it's true, and ironically illustrated well by some of the comments here - is that we often act as though *bad* beginner-level questions are the fault of the asker's innate personal failings - their stupidity, their laziness, or their selfishness - when really they're just impaired by being beginners, and might become useful contributors when they have more experience.

Comment: I think when Yvette talks about changing attitudes here, she's gesturing at a dysfunctional attitude that really does exist in the community - one where we don't just acknowledge that beginner-level questions are permissible and sometimes good, but where we act like beginners are not impaired at all by being beginners, that they are just as *capable* of asking good questions as the rest of us, and that we're therefore justified in reacting with anger and condemnation when they fail. Whatever the solution is, I do think it's fair to call that perspective out for not being rooted in reality.

Comment: To that respect, would it be useful to launch a questionnaire to say, beginners or recent beginners, like under 102 (you get 101 cross site) rep users? To get their perspective. Especially the ones that had their questions flagged/closed. Some stats my shine some light on this. I think we are all trying to address an issue we may not understand what the root cause is.

Comment: @GhostCat - if you ask like that then I guess "yes, at least once a year". But maybe not exactly my (vague) idea and maybe in other circumstances. IMHO Stack Overflow needs some kind of restructuring, maybe a companion "help desk format", or maybe like Lundin's idea "... What would probably work is to let SO be the beginner-site and then create a sister-site for advanced topic". The conflict between users who don't mind answering e.g. duplicate questions and users who see SO solely as the Q&A repo project has been there for years, it might even be alleviated if the "workflow" changes.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes, and the discussions come back, and get to such a point. And then nothing changes. Because that change would require a real money investment ... where is the business case for that?!

Comment: _I did not know what a parameter was._ [ ... and needed help from stackoverflow] Seriously? This is *really* unbelievable! Anyhow, without asking this "dumb" question (or being closed as "too stupid" right away), you would probably have found the Python manual section about "Functions" and you would have learned Python. Wouldn't that be much better?

Comment: @hek2mgl It took me a few goes to work out what was expected of me on SO. Which is why I'm lenient towards newcomers. (not being rude though!). For some people it's harder to get than others. I'm a literal thinker. When reading examples and tutorials I didn't understand for a long time that <some words> was to indicate I substitute my own code in there. I rarely ask questions these days, as I know how to search for the answers.

Comment: Your example is quite different from the original one in question. If I was ever wondering what's the difference between having / not having function parameter, I would expect SO example to pop up when googling it by entering something like "Java function with parameter vs without" in the search bar. But I have absolutely no idea what I would need to search for in order the original "break" example to become relevant and interesting.

Comment: @ZenJ that's because that information should come to you when studying language keywords, or when learning about the individual statements which allow the usage of a break keyword. If you're writing (let's be honest: copy-pasting) code that has break statements in it and you never ever read about it at that point... Stack Overflow is going to be well out of scope.

Comment: I think, the best solution to this problem of beginner questions is an introduction of tag-specific pools or levels. Everyone starts at the beginner's pool. As a member of the beginner's pool, you are not allowed to ask or answer questions in the upper pools. You earn reputation by answering questions in the beginner pool, and once you reach a certain level, you are allowed access to the higher pools. I think 3 levels is enough.

Comment: @SergeyA This approach would bring at least two new problems: (1) How would we sort questions in pools? (2) How would we grant exemptions for new users who happen to be experts in something?

Comment: @duplode we do not sort. Every question posted as a beginner ends up in the beginner pool.

Comment: @SergeyA In that case, what happens if a "beginner" posts an advanced question? And who's to say a "beginner" question can't benefit from an answer by a non-beginner user?

Comment: @duplode nothing stops non-beginners from going into beginners pool and answering questions they find interesting there. There might be even a special filter, beginners questions with no answers or something like that.

Answer (score 18):

I often vote to close such questions as off-topic:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

This may or may not be stretching the intended meaning of "can no longer be reproduced".

I use this closing reason only in cases where OP clearly "mistyped" the code. That is, when people answer the question (often in comments), OP writes something like "OMG such an obvious bug, I feel dumb for not seeing it".

An easy way to deal with these questions would be by giving OP the chance to "agree" with the closing reason. Something that helps OP say "Yes, this question is about a typo in my code - this question cannot help anyone else - reduce discoverability of this question".

I know that something like this already exists for "duplicate" closing reason - I (as OP) can "vote to close" my own question as duplicate after someone votes for it, and my "vote" is final.

So, my suggestion is:

1. Move the "typo" closing reason from the "off-topic" bunch into a separate choice
2. If someone voted "typo" on the question, present some UI for OP, which says "Yes, it's a dumb question, and I got my answer"
3. If OP presses on the UI, close the question immediately, and mark it somehow "irrelevant" in the database to make it less likely to come up in searches

Comment: The suggestion in this answer [is an abuse of the suggested close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348025/4639281). For those that are doing this already, please stop. For those who read this answer and think that abusing this close reason is a good idea, please don't.

Comment: Which "suggestion" are you referring to? My post has several of them, better clarify which one you are talking about to prevent confusion.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that I'm referring to the suggestion to abuse an existing close reason for things it was explicitly never meant to be used for, and to the fact that you said you're already abusing such close reason for said purpose.

Answer (score 9):

I would have closed this with the "simple typo" option. Because I don't think it is a beginner mistake.

It seems likely that the `break` is just some slip that happened while rewriting the code. If the OP knows what `break` does, then they will recognize the problem as a silly mistake as soon as they spot it.

Why would a beginner type a random keyword in the middle of their loop if they don't know what that keyword does? Sure, beginners do strange things, but if they have no clue about what it does, the name of the keyword is rather dramatic and should be off-putting. If I add this, will something break? Uh-oh, better use this with caution.

That being said, the "too localized" close reason was good to have. SO is a significantly worse site now than it was when it had "too localized" and "must demonstrate minimal knowledge" close reasons. But that was back in the days when it was still a site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: Sometimes reading some questions I feel that the code provided in the question was written by a teacher, and the assignment was "make the code work" or similar

Comment: Agree with @Zenj here. Sometimes I feel the code has been lifted from / merged from another source and the user is simply unable to adapt it for their use case. (That practice, without understanding, is of course *bad*, but SO isn't a good platform for teaching good learning practices.)

Answer (score 6):

A few spur-of-the-moment thoughts:

- #1 is a tough sell, as [the reasons that led "too localized" to be dropped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/242059) (high potential for misuse, mostly) presumably still apply.
- As for #2 and #3, the devil lies in what counts as "appropriately worded". I suspect beginner mistakes isn't quite what we would want to aim at, but rather unenlightening problems. Not all beginner mistakes are created equal. Some are completely uninteresting, like the one you have shown here; others, however, are rooted in something worth explaining here. In particular, a common mistake of general interest deserves a proper duplicate target.
- #4 is an interesting idea. It reminds me a bit of [this suggestion of creative use of wiki answers to handle typo questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343108/2751851). I suspect the main hurdle would be differentiating such a feature from the establishment of [a parallel system of second-class disposable questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155119/242059), which is broadly considered a bad idea as it would encourage, and arguably endorse, posting questions with no long-term value. (I'm fairly sure there was another feature request about temporary questions that had more extensive discussion, but I couldn't find it yet.)

Comment: Your bullet 1).  Yes.  But if the "too localized" could be used only for Questions with Answers?  Your bullet 2) Yes agreed!  Your bullet 3) But counter to your counter is the fact that the current settings are is encouraging these questions anyway ... because of welcoming-ness.

Comment: @StephenC Here is an attempt to look in another way at what it would mean to have a close reason that only applies to answered questions. The curation mechanisms we have here can have several goals, including (a) Stopping poor questions from becoming part of the library in the long run; (b) Stopping poor questions from diverting the attention of contributors by taking up space in question feeds and review queues; and (c) Stopping users that consistently post poor questions from doing so. As far as I can see, this new mechanism would mostly aim at (a). Would that be enough?

Comment: Agreed: probably not enough.  But there is not enough space in a meta Question to propose solutions for all of the problems that need addressing :-)

Comment: The main issue I have is *any* closure reason that doesn't give OP the answer they need/want is likely to cause friction. Marking as a duplicate, which *most* basic questions *are*, is *less likely* to cause friction because they might find an answer which helps them.

Comment: @jpp Duplicate closure is a good tool indeed, and [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377359/2751851) makes that case well. Some questions, though, are so uninteresting that even the modest effort of maintaining a duplicate target and retrieving it whenever necessary feels like being too much.

Comment: @duplode, Yep, I do appreciate the problem. I am biased. I now *almost exclusively* use review queues to review duplicates in my gold-badge tags. It's more rewarding for me (I learn more from canonicals), probably save hours of contributors' time (by unilateral closing), and contribute more in my areas of expertise (editing / adding to canonicals).

Answer (score 4):

A quick, totally not at all thought-through suggestion: some sort of new flag/close reason which marks the question for deletion/auto-roomba after *n* days or once it has been [marked as] answered. This allows newbies to get their question answered, but doesn’t clutter up the search results in all perpetuity; in effect giving both sides what they want.

Perhaps the answerer could tick a box along the lines of “this topic is too specific and this answer has no general value” for this to take effect.

The difference to the existing close/delete workflow would be that a question can be “preemptively deleted”, as opposed to 5 CVs followed by 3 DVs, while still allowing it some grace period to be answered.

Comment: But there might be useful information in there. Perhaps a flag option for those questions, *"**Retain**. This question has lasting value and deserves to stay (not auto-deleted)."*?

Comment: Well, we’re explicitly talking about questions with *no* lasting value here, which nonetheless don’t really fit existing close reasons.

Comment: This fits in what I was thinking but I was aiming my solution more at altering the current interface while this may be easier to not drastically change the current process for review.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the question quoted asks "Why does my program break out of the loop?".

The simplest answer is: "You have a break statement within the loop.".

It *could* be answered with a comment and self-deleted, but not if answers are given. We could keep the question so duplicates would be attached to it, but it's only a FAQ if it's a common mistake and not something unlikely to be asked again.

What constitutes preserving versus deleting is an opinion, like a vote most people have one; it's a flag category that is missing.

This category of question could be resolved politely with a flag called: "**The question or product documentation contains the answer**".

Such questions invite an explanation of what can plainly be seen by many people, but for some reason was missed by the one asking. It is true that something that is *obvious* to many people might escape notice by both expert and novice.

Flagging the question as self-evident allows both expert and beginner to re-read their question and determine for themselves if there is something they might have missed.

Let's look at another slightly more complicated example: [Terminating a Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-a-java-program)

```
public class Testing {

public static void main(String... str) {
    System.out.println(1);
    System.exit(0);
    System.out.println(2);
    return;
 }
}
```

It has 50 upvotes and 275,253 views in almost 5 years.

The OP's question is:

> "I am sure that 2 will not appear. [What] I would like to know is why return; or other codes can write below the statement of System.exit(0); and what was real definition for return; (because it is strange thing for me return without any variables or values) ?"

**IF** the OP had read the documentation for the commands they were using or performed a search they might have found: "[Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)" which clearly explains:

> "Any method declared void doesn't return a value. It does not need to contain a return statement, but it may do so. In such a case, a return statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block and exit the method and is simply used like this:
>
> ```
>  return;
> ```
>
> If you try to return a value from a method that is declared void, you will get a compiler error.
>
> Any method that is not declared void must contain a return statement with a corresponding return value, like this:
>
> ```
> return returnValue;
> ```
>
> The data type of the return value must match the method's declared return type; you can't return an integer value from a method declared to return a boolean.

The slightly more complicated question has value (for some people) and the votes/views bear that out. Without a flag to explain people's reaction to the question the OP must rely on votes and comments.

A bunch of downvotes for a newcomer might be interpreted as unfriendly, perhaps they will find it helpful to know that they need to take a second look at what they are asking; but they feel ruined, their few precious reputation points gone, back to the bottom.

A flag that contains a comment suggesting that they should have another try at answering their own question encourages them to learn on their own, rather than running outside and yelling to the world that they have a simple problem that they are unable to resolve.

Many of us have stayed up too long trying to finish something when a rest, and a view from a fresh perspective, is what is needed. A flag such as I have suggested says: 'Hey buddy, take another look at what you are asking' without being quite so blunt.

We all need a little help sometimes, other times the greatest benefit (for everyone) is that we learn to help ourselves. I agree that we need a flag for the situation, rather than a 'downvote pile on' or answers offered where one must bite their tongue while answering.

Comment: A wonderful use of SO is as an index to the official documentation of major programming languages. Googing "how to do x in Java", clicking through to SO, and if necessary through into the docs, is much easier than going to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html and reading it all. As such "The question or product documentation contains the answer" is in no way a good close reason.

Comment: No. [Official Policy on Copying Content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320589/official-policy-on-copying-content), [Do not copy the complete text of external sources ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), [Can I copy paste an answer from an (external) webpage?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/can-i-copy-paste-an-answer-from-an-external-webpage), etc. --- No need to read it all, use the search. We are not a *sub-search* but a value-added product. A self-evident question is simply that, but the concern here is to express that politely.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that a straight copy-paste of docs is a good idea. Rather, many questions on SO link common problems, expressed in natural language, to the relevant page(s) of the API docs. E.g. The question of [how to print in Python without a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space) has a comprehensive answer for a variety of Python versions. It's unlikely that typing your question in the Python API search would get you that. That sort of question is highly valuable (1.5 M views!) but ultimately fails your criterion.

Answer (score -5):

I think "unclear what you are asking" is appropriate for these questions. The answer is obvious for anyone with minimal understanding, so it is *unclear* why the asker does not understand. Alternatively, the asker does not understand the basics (of looping in this case), and needs a tutorial or a course of instruction, in which case "too broad" is appropriate.

Comment: These are tempting options, but there is a catch. If we use "unclear what you're asking" for questions that are clear to readers on a literal level because it is unclear why they are being asked, or if we use "too broad" for questions that can be answered in half a dozen words because they suggest the asker needs a tutorial, we end up making it about the asker rather than the question. I would much rather have a close reason with language that indicates what is wrong with the question itself. See also the comments to [Yvette's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377351).

Comment: The example on the question is about a mistake on programming logic, something that a good IDE like eclipse would detect and warn.

Answer (score -6):

**Flag and triage**

**EDIT: I do now see the error in this approach, I would delete it but the comments might make sense for other people thinking this way.**

This could easily be an additional flag and be reviewed in triage.

Have a sub menu in **requires editing** that asks a quetion towards the author and will unlist/unindex the question until the author has edited their question:

Option could be (but not limited to):#

- Bad English / grammar / formatting (which can also be dealt with by anyone else)
- Syntax errors that can be easily solved with an IDE or similar. Author can fix these errors or close the post if that was the issue
- Not enough information or not enough code to solve the problem

The reviewer can have a free text box to leave additional information.

Once edited the question will be reviewed for its edit again and if **Look OK** it will be re-added to the index.

I still believe SO should be open for all and people and not everyone is good at using a search index (SO search, google etc). We should not piss people off and discourage them to learn.

Comment: That goes counter to the "requires editing" usage. "Requires editing" means that users _other than the author_ can fix the post. Two of your three examples are directed to the post author. Are you sure you are using the _requires editing_ option correclty?

Comment: Someone else already made this comment an hour ago and I did respond to that, but yes I might have used it wrong int he past and yes we all know the interface is misleading, but the point is that when you click unsalvageable, you are kind of condemning the author, no ?

Comment: No, you are not condeming the author. You are reviewing **content**, not **users**. If the content is not good for the site, the post author needs to be made aware so they can fix it. Closing questions is a very important part of quality control and content curation. If you disagree with clicking _unsalvageable_, maybe is better if you do not use the review queues. If we didn't need to close posts, we wouldn't need the queues.

Comment: Right but the topic is still beginners / new users, no ? I mean if the author post 3 questions and all of his 3 posts get closed without constructive criticism, you are in fact condemning the author. The topic of the Q/A is about beginners, not beginners posts ( not directly anyway). I do understand we need to keep the site clean, but I do not think we should be so harsh in the resolution. I consider myself a beginner on Meta/SO, and I will probably always be, but I know opensource all to well, and if a certain group is no longer welcome SO looses all properties of **community driven**

Comment: Each of the close reasons do give constructive criticism though, it's impossible to close a question without giving useful feedback.

Comment: Well then I'll just give up. If I am having problems after 8 years of using SO I bet I am not the only one. What is constructive for you may not be for everyone else.

Comment: @DarkMukke You might find [Mark Amery's comments to Yvette's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377349/a-welcoming-way-to-winnow-out-the-dumb-questions?noredirect=1#comment652512_377351) interesting.

Answer (score -6):

## A dissent:

> OK. That's a dumb question

**It's not a dumb question.** It might be a simple question, but so long as the person who asked it asked in good faith, *someone* out there was honestly mystified.

> But, we don't really want questions like that in the long term. They help nobody but the OP.

On the contrary: We want lots of those question in there long term, and we want to make it as easy as possible for people to find them, so that we don't have to answer those same beginner questions over and over. Again, the OP asked because they didn't know the answer, and it's certain that other beginners will run into the same problem from time to time. If you were so inclined, you could take 10 minutes to write a really solid answer, and you'd probably gain rep from it for *years*.

> Once someone has answered, they are (frankly) a waste of time to even read.

To you, a 500K+ user, perhaps, but SO is about helping each other by answering questions, and that doesn't just mean questions that are interesting or challenging to you.

I appreciate that you're trying to think of ways to get rid of simple questions without being unkind, but **the kind and helpful thing to do here is to leave simple questions alone or answer them**.

## A compromise:

It might be helpful to create a tag for beginner mistakes, so that really simple stuff can be easily identified. If you're not interested in seeing very simple questions, you can add the [simple-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-question) tag to your ignore list. Beginners could benefit from watching that tag and trying to answer the questions themselves.

We'd need to be careful to have clear criteria for what makes a simple question, so that the tag doesn't get overused and become meaningless. And it'd be good to try to create a fun atmosphere around it, so that nobody feels too badly if their question is so tagged. A funny name for the tag, like [doh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doh) (although that one's taken) or [smack-my-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smack-my-head) or [facepalm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facepalm), could help there. Pointing the tag out in the help material would make it more visible.

Comment: I just want to mention that all of your name suggestions could be **very** insulting. Including `simple-questions`. This very much depends on the asker's culture and state of mind.

Comment: It would be very hard to hit with such a tag. Perhaps `beginner-question` may be soft enough - I would shy away from comedy.

Comment: @kabanus They certainly weren't meant to be insulting, and feel free to suggest alternatives. The point isn't to put anybody down, but rather to make it safe for beginners to ask questions that even they know are probably pretty simple. People often have a reaction like "Doh!" when the answer is pointed out.

Comment: I know, and I like the sentiment and suggestion, I just think it would be hard to implement. `beginner-question` seems OK to me, but I'm one guy. The main problem is people not from the US or English speaking countries, may miss the light hearted, warm sentiment (specifically for Doh! as well) - that is exactly how people seem unwelcoming to each other without meaning to.

Comment: @kabanus I think it's far more unwelcoming to see your question get closed because it was "dumb" than to have it put in a category like "simple mistakes that anybody can make." I think it'd really work out best if the OP him/herself tags the question as being simple, but SO novices likely wouldn't realize that they can/should do that. Anyway, I hear you, and I'm not too attached to any particular tag name.

Comment: Historical context relevant to the tag proposal: _[The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)_ ; _[Would a "facepalm" tag be useful/fun?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289641/would-a-facepalm-tag-be-useful-fun)_

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair enough, and I get the problem with meta tags. OTOH the popularity of this question speaks to a desire to avoid simple questions, and I think being able to search for them (in combination with other tags) could be valuable. Anyway, the important point is that we shouldn't close honest questions just because they're simple and then wonder why newbies think SO is unfriendly.

Comment: @Caleb: but we still should close them as duplicates where and whenever possible – right? Which *in itself* is considered "unwelcoming" by some – because they did not get 'their' answer...

Comment: We shouldn't close a question just because it's simple, no, agreed. As long as we also don't _not_ close a question _just_ because it's by a beginner.

Comment: A good dissenting opinion, even though I don't necessarily agree. To me, it seems there is a threshold of triviality below which even retrieving the question for later use can become difficult, as there is little for a searcher to latch onto. There is also the matter of scale -- the attention of searchers, answer writers, and curators are all limited resources. I do agree with "dumb" not being the notion we actually want to use here -- not only it is vague, it also slides too easily into making it about the poster rather than the post.

Comment: @usr2564301 If the question really is really a dupe and the prior question has answers that cover the one in question, then sure, close it just as we would any other dupe. But don't be more aggressive about closing simple questions just because they're simple.

Comment: @duplode We should apply Dumbledore's standard: *"Help will always be given at Hogwarts to those who ask for it.... But i would in this case amend my original statement: help is always given at Hogwarts to those who deserve it."* So I'd close "give me teh codez" questions and those that show little effort, but answer those where someone seems to have put some effort into the problem and the question. And we can use these questions to grow our resources: a simple question doesn't need an expert answer — leave it for novices to answer so they build rep and become part of the community.

Comment: @Caleb "So I'd close 'give me teh codez' questions and those that show little effort [...]" -- This sounds like the kind of sliding I mentioned above. I don't think we should care about how much effort was actually spent on a question, but rather about whether the end result is something that can be useful in the long run. See these answers to [*Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909) and [*Is “too broad” a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185).

Comment: @duplode Fair enough -- I think there's a correspondence between effort expended and utility, but it is indeed utility that we should care about.

Comment: Why does this loop not loop? `while(foo) {print(foo); break}` _is_ a dumb question. No matter how you turn it

Answer (score -12):

I don't think it is a "dumb" question. It certainly isn't a "bad" question, it has: a reproducable code example, and a clear difference between the desired state (the code should be looping) and the actual state (the code is not looping), and therefore the question: why isn't the code looping?

Also I don't think the question helps only OP, anyone who is new to loops can benefit from this, imagine them searching for "how to stop a loop" and finding this, it would probably be helpful to them to know the `break` keyword, as someone would surely explain it in the answer, or link to a simple loop tutorial.

I once thought about adding a "RTFM" close reason with link to a tutorial for these "beginner" questions such as "what is the difference between `long` and `int`, how to define a function, etc.), but you can just answer them and link the tutorial in the answer for further reading, so I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: If they wrote the break keyword there on purpose, without knowing what it does, then of course it's a dumb question. However, I think it's far more likely that the break ended up there during some re-write of the code, a copy/paste error or similar.

Comment: *"anyone who is new to loops can benefit from this"* - Anyone, who is new to loops, is not (yet) a programmer. As such, whoever may find the information useful is not the intended target audience of Stack Overflow. [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This may not be a bad question, but it sure as hell does **not** belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By that logic this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java is a sumb question as well. After all the programmer wouldn't use `==` unless they wanted to compare the refernces, right?
You assume that everyone who comes to SO has to already know how the `break` keyword work, but not knowing how string comparison work is apparently OK.

Comment: *"Identity"* and *"equality"* are highly abstract concepts. Loops are basic, concrete, hard-to-not-grasp, fundamental concepts. What's more, when you *actively* write the `break` keyword, and then come here to ask, why it does what its intended purpose is, it's hard to argue that question were *not* utterly dumb, useless noise.