# More useless long sentence titles from new contributors

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-wizard-2018

I'm seeing *more* questions from new "contributors" that have a long, descriptive title that is, despite that, worthless. For example:

> Following exception is getting thrown while trying to create Elastic Search Index through loaders in Java. Any help would be appreciated

Let me emphasize: that is a question **title**. It manages quite a high fault density:

- Not self contained ("Following")
- Uses words that can be tags instead (Elasticsearch, Java). Not always a problem, but if you are posting about a specific exception,  the language is implicit anyway, and removing tags is a way of shortening a long title.
- Begging ("Any help.. ")
- Vague where precision would not be more verbose (*what* type of exception?)
- Not telegraph/ headline style ("is getting thrown" rather than "thrown"). Again, not always a problem, but definitely a problem when the title is already lengthy and verbose.

As my subjective perception is that there are more of these very recently,  I wonder if the introduction of the new question wizard is encouraging posting of these kinds of titles.

If so, perhaps that wizard should be tweaked to discourage titles like that?

It looks like the new users are now mistaking the title field for the body field more than previously.

---

Does this matter? Well, garbage titles like that  deserve downvotes for not being useful. And I believe they are correlated with unsalvageable bad questions. So if the new question wizard is *encouraging* questions written like this,  it is setting up new "contributors" to fail, which is the opposite of being "welcoming".

Comment: That's a rather roundabout way of saying that new users are mistaking the title field for the body field. This is, verbatim, the sort of thing you'd see in a question body from new users.

Comment: At least it's not like that one user from a few years ago who thought "title" was "job title" and every one of their questions had a title that was some variation of "php web developer"

Comment: Any indication that question was posted using the [ask question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing?cb=1)? The wizard asks for the title first (so it can do its find similar questions trick) and users might be afraid they have no other option to include more details so they start by sharing as much as is allowed.

Comment: It is such an excellent hint at the amount of effort you'll have to expect when answering such a question.  Editing the title is the easy part.  I don't mind a newbie question, occasionally, being able to filter them up front from the home page is quite useful.

Comment: Writing titles is almost as hard as choosing names.  Writing the best titles many times require a good understanding of the subject; and as such is not easily findable by other users who do not have that understanding yet. It’s not surprising many users mess it up. If the question is not bad, fixing the title is simple enough for expert users and a great thing to do for the repository. Many, many times; you may end up finding a good duplicate target by doing it.

Comment: We can’t have enough information to know if these are posted through the wizard or not. But this is the kind of thing that’s easy to look for with access to all the data; and pretty sure this kinf of analysis is one of the experiment’s objectives.

Comment: I don’t see not using headlinese nor the inclusion of tags (naturally not tacked on) as being problems. It’s the begging and the fact a specific error isn’t mentioned that are problems (but are also easy to fix manually). The fact that the title mentions where exactly the error happens is a big plus, so it’s not actually that bad of a title I think.

Comment: Info: It's ok to have the title contain some information that can be in tags instead if [they are organic to the conversational tone of the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: IIRC, there is no "use professional tone" note on the old "ask question" page or the new wizard, so it's not weird that users don't know about it.

Comment: By the way, how was the question body?

Comment: @user202729: [Exactly what one would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53910315/1) in such a case.

Comment: @user202729 But it's OK. Someone edited it to put the useless question body in a code block. Phew!

Comment: For what it's worth, I was seeing noisy, multi-sentence titles before the Ask Wizard went live.

Comment: @BSMP So was I. That's why my question talks about there being **more** of them.

Comment: @BoltClock IMO, the title that's brought to attention by this Meta question is only marginally better than a *php web developer*. It provides no more useful information than the keywords *exception, Elastic Search* and *Java*. (But I must admit that I laughed at that "title", seriously, wahaha!)

Comment: Fwiw, the author of the question whose title is referenced here is in the control group for the wizard experiment; they would've used the old Ask form.

Answer (score 17):

I strongly disagree with Ian Kemp's answer. While I'm not certain whether the slew of bad titled questions are due to the poor performance of the Wizard, I do firmly believe that if the question is salvageable, you should make every attempt to fix it. Sometimes, users have a hard time describing their problem, or even understanding the source of their issue, so a lot of times the title will be poorly worded, or will not accurately describe what their question is *actually* about.

My rule of thumb is: if you think the question is good enough for you to answer, then you should edit the title to be as canonical as possible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53923282/revisions) is the revision history of one of the most recent posts I overhauled. Here, I've edited the title to be as searchable as possible, fixed the wording, and improved the question's MCVE. While this might be overkill, the title is a good example of how I usually edit the questions I answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53911645/revisions) is another similar example where I edited just the title and tags for a pandas question.

OTOH, trash will be trash, and your should realize when something is not worth the effort. What is important is being able to make the distinction between what is salvageable, and what isn't. If we want the site to become more welcoming, I suggest starting here.

Answer (score -5):

No, please don't do anything about sentences in titles. They are an important hint (in most cases, an almost certain guarantee) of a "question" that is irredeemable trash. Advising help vampires that they shouldn't put sentences in titles will only help them to better hide their trash in plain sight.

And please don't attempt to "fix" such trash questions either. Downvote and VTC and for the love of $deity$, **please** don't close as a dupe; not only does it waste your time and effort looking for a target, it also means the Roomba can't deliver final judgement on the trash.

Comment: ...Interesting... Please, tell us more.

Comment: Oh, yes, I agree, those questions are unsalvageable. But if the question wizard could turn the new "contributor" aside *before* it gets posted, that would help. "As it is, your question is probably too low quality for StackOverflow. Consider revision its [part] to [effect change]. If you post low quality questions you may be blocked from posting more."

Comment: In fact, some of the research done on Stack Overflow by 3rd parties has shown that questions whose titles are phrased as questions (with proper complete sentence structure and grammar) get more and better answers. Wish I had that paper bookmarked...

Comment: `it also means the Roomba can't deliver final judgement on the trash`. That's not true. [Downvoted dupilcates do get roomba'd.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210263/383944) Related: [A welcoming way to winnow out the “dumb” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377349/a-welcoming-way-to-winnow-out-the-dumb-questions).

Comment: I disagree with this, because a good number of questions can be salvaged just by fixing the title.

Comment: But not every useless-title questions lacks MCVE and is poorly formatted like this specific-question.

Comment: While I agree they are often a HINT at what to expect in a question, sometimes the question is still salvageable, so simply downvoting or VTCing where a simple edit would fix it seems far too drastic.